# Blender version 3.0.0 grease pencil layer incorrectly renders over 3d objects

Tags: grease-pencil

Blender version 2.93 will correctly render a grease pencil layer, regardless of stroke depth order, behind a 3d object that is closer than the grease pencil layer.

[image]

Blender version 3.0.0 incorrectly renders the grease pencil layer in-front of the 3d object regardless of the stroke depth order.
[image]

I've uninstalled a September 2021 installation of 3.0.0 and reinstalled the most current distribution.

Am I missing anything? Does anyone have a solution or work around for this apparent bug?

Comment: Have you checked if that bug is already reported, and if not, posted a bug report?

Comment: I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the answer at your screenshot:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that you have z pass disabled:

[image]

Comment: Seems that in 3.0.0 by default View Layer Properties>Passes>Data Z is set to false while in 2.93 it is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I'v got another trouble. Grease pencil, that were posted behind the 2d png picture, overlapped it.
That was solved buy changing Blend Mode from "Alpha Blend" to "Alpha Hashed" into png Material properties -> Settings.[image]